# Why is this div completely invisible to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div (the topmost one in the markup below) in my HTML code that I'm trying to find via jQuery `.children()`. For some reason jQuery just can't find it.

This can be tested by running this:

```
$($('<p class="info-item"><span class="info-item-key">Gender:</span><span class="info-item-value">Male</span><span class="info-item-edit-button">&nbsp;<a class="black-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i></a></span><div class="form-inline info-item-edit-input"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" /><div class="input-group-addon"><a class="black-link info-item-edit-save-link"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></div></div></div></div></p>')[0]).children()
```

Here is the same markup contained in that code, but better formatted:

```
<p class="info-item">
    <span class="info-item-key">Gender:</span>
    <span class="info-item-value">Male</span>
    <span class="info-item-edit-button">
        &nbsp;<a class="black-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i></a>
    </span>
    <div class="form-inline info-item-edit-input">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <a class="black-link info-item-edit-save-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

For context, I'm trying to use jQuery to show the edit form when the edit button is clicked.

Is there any reason why this div seems to be invisible to jQuery? `.contents()` can't find it either. (Try it.)

If it helps, that div is initially hidden with `display: none` in CSS, but even trying it in a JS console session attached to a document that doesn't have that CSS results in the div not being found either. (Try it in the StackOverflow JS console, or any other site, if you want.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the markup is invalid. `div` can't be child of a `p` element. `p` element can only have [phrasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/content-models.html#phrasing-content-1).

Consider this simple example:

```
$('<p><div></div></p>');
```

This is how my Chromium browser renders the above markup:

```
<p></p><div></div><p></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, changing the `p` to a `span` and wrapping the text bits in a `p` has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following fiddle shows you how to access the div you are looking for. I added some text within the div so you can see the alert.

https://jsfiddle.net/xw9Lteww/1/

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   alert($(".form-inline").text()); 
});
```

HTML

```
<p class="info-item">
<span class="info-item-key">Gender:</span>
<span class="info-item-value">Male</span>
<span class="info-item-edit-button">
    &nbsp;<a class="black-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i></a>
</span>
<div class="form-inline info-item-edit-input">
    hey
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <a class="black-link info-item-edit-save-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</p>
```